# Temporarily disabling default services in servicefabric using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

### The concrete question

For those who just want the direct questions:

- Is there a way to temporarily disable default services on a ServiceFabric application type so that a new application can be installed (using Powershell) without automatically installing any default services?
- A proposed solution here is to remove the default services from the manifest and later restoring them. I am able to write a PowerShell script to adjust the application manifest accordingly, but how do I update the application type using Powershell - assuming I already have altered the manifest?

**Any solution that solves the contextual problem without requiring manual config meddling is acceptable** - my proposed solution is probably not the only possible solution. We do explicitly want to avoid manual meddling.

When allowing meddling, we are already able to just comment out the default services when we need to. We're specifically looking for a solution that requires no meddling as this reduces bugs and debugging issues.

---

### The context

I'm running into an issue with using the application manifest's default services during local development.

I am aware of the general "don't use default services" advice, and it is being followed. During CI build, the default services are removed and will not be relied upon for any of our clusters in Azure. The only exception here is local developer machines, which use default services to keep the developer F5 experience nicer by enabling all services when starting a debug session.

We have written specialized scripts that provision a new tenant (SF application) with their own set of services (SF service). Not every tenant should get every service, we want to opt-in to the services, which is what the script already does (based on a mapping that we manage elsewhere, which is not part of the current question as the provisioning script exists and works).

However, when default services are enabled, every tenant already gets every service and the actual opt-in provisioning is useless. This is the issue we're trying to fix.
This same script works in our production cluster since there are no default services configured there. The question is solely focus on the local development environment.

Essentially, we're dealing with two scenarios during local development:

- When debugging, we want the default services to be on because it allows us to run all of our services by pressing F5 (and not requiring any further action)
- When testing our provisioning script, we don't want default services because it gets in the way of our selective provisioning behavior

I'm aware that commenting the default services out of the manifest solves the issue, but this requires developers constantly toggling the content of the manifest and reinstalling the application type, which we'd like to avoid.
Ideally, we want to have the default services in the manifest (as is currently the case) but then have the provisioning script "disable" the default services for its own runtime (and restore the default services before exiting), as this gets us the desired behavior in both cases.

What is the solution that requires the least manual developer meddling to get the desired behavior in both scenarios?

I'm currently trying to implement it so that the provisioning script:

1. Copies the application manifest to a backup location
2. Removes the default services from the real manifest
3. Updates the application type using the new manifest (i.e. without default services)
4. Runs the provisioning logic
5. Restores the real manifest using the backup manifest from step 1
6. Updates the application type using the restored manifest (i.e. with default services)

It is specifically steps 3 and 6 that I do not know how to implement.

Comment: It’s not clear from you question why you need to provision the application type with default services at all. What’s stopping you from simply removing default services in CI and leave it at that?

Comment: @JohnNilsson: On azure, everything works. But when we make changes to the provisioning script, we want to test it locally before deploying it. Locally, the default services are blocking us from testing if the script correctly provisions _some_ of the services, which is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @JohnNilsson: Just to be clear: we want the default services locally because it's nice and easy when developing a service and wanting to debug it. It's only when we test the provisioning script locally that we don't want these default services to be installed automatically. I'm looking for a way to suspend that default service installation _only during the provisioning script_, not during a normal debug session; without requiring developers to manually adjust the manifest every time. I'm looking for a way to script these adjustments, provision the services, and then restore the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider having two sfproj projects in the solution. One with default services, one without.

Also look into using a start-service.ps1 script instead of default services. This way the two projects can use the same application manifest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application#running-a-script-as-part-of-debugging

Comment: If I have two projects which rely on the same manifest, isn't the only difference between them how the application is deployed? If that's the difference, can't I then just upgrade an existing application (adding/removing default services) instead of deploying a new one?

Comment: Lost me again I’m afraid. The point of this setup would be that they only differ in how they are deployed yes. One sfproj would have that automatic deployment of default services, for development. The other would not, allowing you to test other deployment scenarios.

Using a startup script would of course make it possible to use some other condition for when and what to deploy instead of having multiple sfprojs.

Comment: The core question is how (or if) I can adjust the default services of an existing application type, as opposed to running two different application types with different sets of default services. Assume the application is already installed, how do I change its default services (you can assume I've already updated the application manifest accordingly)

Comment: I don’t think there is any other way to do that then simply provisioning the type with different manifests.

But if you only need default services for dev, there is no reason to flip back and forth. Just don’t have any default services in the manifest and leave it at that. Use a start script instead.